# What is a good structure to a project with JSF 2 and JPA 2?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsf, jpa, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

My idea is : I have a bean (**UserBean**) which have some attributes to help me validate before I set into the entity **User**. I'm doing that to reuse the validate in the **UserBean** attribute in the whole project and to keep separated the layers as I could read in a lot of posts here in the *stack overflow*. 
Knowing that I would like to keep the MVC structure, let's see what I do so far:

[image: structure]

( Sorry about the big picture I thought it would be more easier understand my question)

This is my User (in entity package):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private int reputation;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Company
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Company company;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Location
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Location> locations;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Person
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
    private Person person;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Product> products;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserType
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="type")
    private UserType userType;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserPhone
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserPhone> userPhones;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserPicture
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserPicture> userPictures;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserSocialNetwork
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserSocialNetwork> userSocialNetworks;

       // getters and setters

}
```

And this is his bean , UserBean (in bean.entity package):

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1626847931067187536L;

    private int id;

    @NotNull(message="informe seu e-mail")
    @Email(message="e-mail inválido")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "6 dígitos no mínimo")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 128, message = "6 dígitos no mínimo")
    private String password;

    @NotNull(message = "6 dígitos no mínimo")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 128, message = "6 dígitos no mínimo")
    private String password_2;

    private int reputation;

    private UserType userType;

    private List<UserPhoneBean> userPhones;

    private List<UserPicture> userPictures;

    private List<UserSocialNetwork> userSocialNetworks;

    @AssertTrue(message = "senhas diferentes")
    public boolean isPasswordsEquals() {
        return password.equals(password_2);
    }

        // getters and setters

}
```

Then every action that has to do with the User I would like to keep the control in one place, so I create the **UserControl** bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userc")
@ViewScoped
public class UserControl implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1626847931067187536L;

    @EJB EaoUser eaoUser;
    @EJB EaoPerson eaoPerson;

    @ManagedProperty("#{userBean}")
    private UserBean user;

    @ManagedProperty("#{personBean}")
    private PersonBean person;

    private UserBean ub;
    private PersonBean pb;

    private View view;


    public UserControl() {
        ub = new UserBean();
        pb = new PersonBean();
        view = new View();
    }

    public String login(){
        List<User> list = eaoUser.findByEmail(ub.getEmail());
        User u = list.get(0);

            if (Crypto.check(ub.getPassword(), u.getPassword())){
                HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false); 
                session.setAttribute("authenticated", true);

                user = new UserBean();
                user.setId(u.getId());
                user.setEmail(u.getEmail());
                user.setPassword(u.getPassword());
                user.setReputation(u.getReputation());

                user.setUserType(u.getUserType());

                if (u.getUserType().getId() == 10){
                    Person p = eaoPerson.find(u.getId());

                    if (p != null){
                        person = new PersonBean();
                        person.setName(p.getName());
                        person.setSurname(p.getSurname());
                        person.setBirthdate(p.getBirthdate());
                        person.setGender(p.getGender());
                    }
                }

                for (UserPhone up : u.getUserPhones()){
                    user.getUserPhones().add(new UserPhoneBean(up.getId(), up.getPhone()));
                }

                user.setUserPictures(u.getUserPictures());
                user.setUserSocialNetworks(u.getUserSocialNetworks());

            }else{
                view.imageError();
                view.setStatus("e-mail ou senha incorretos");
                view.setPopup(true);

                return "#";
            }

        return "secured/user/home?faces-redirect=true";
    }
        // others method, getters and setters
}
```

Note that I'm injecting the **userBean** here in **userControl**, so when the user log in I rescue the value from the database and set in the userBean.

I create the attribute **user** and **ub** because when I try to validate with the **user** the validation it seems to not work, I guess it is because he's injected already (just a guess).

So, after all this explanation, when I try to log in, the **user** (whic is injected) don't keep any value anymore.

If I try to do this:

```
Welcome, <h:outputText value="#{userc.user.email}" />
```

Don't appears nothing..

So I wonder if my structure is correct.
What you guys think about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem has nothing to do with the project structure.

The real problem is here, in the `login()` method:

```
user = new UserBean();
```

You're overriding a JSF-injected managed bean by a manually created bean. This one won't be used by JSF and gets lost after the view leaves. The JSF-injected managed property `user` shouldn't be `null` at that point. You don't need to create it yourself. Remove that line altogether.

But you've other bigger problems, that copying of properties from one `User` to other `User` is totally unnecessary. Basically, you need to add a `User` property to the `UserBean` class and do a `user.setUser(user);` instead. This way it's available by `#{userBean.user.email}`. I would only maybe rename the one or other so that the EL code makes more sense. You'd like to end up as something like `#{user.current.email}` or `#{login.user.email}` or `#{auth.user.email}`, etc.

Comment: GREAAT mate! Thanks, your suggestion was right, I had to that because was giving me some NullPointerException at that point.

Your idea about userBean.set(user) was awesome. Just one thing, in the userBean I keep the attributes to make the validation, just add the right ? Or have some way to reuse the attributes from the User (entity) ?

Comment: That NPE was likely caused because you didn't have the `@ManagedProperty` first. As to the JSR 303 validation annotations, you can indeed just put them straight on the `User`, but you've only to keep the 2nd password field in the `UserBean` (or `UserController`). Actually, with a bit proper `Validator`, you don't need that field at all. Only, I would not bind the login form to a session scoped bean, but to the `UserController` instead, which in turn should also have a `User` property to bind the login form fields. Then, when you login, set the found JPA User entity in the `UserBean`.